# Is sqlite database creted on both server and client's device?

Tags: php, sqlite, local-storage, mobile-website, emplace

i have recently update my website files to my server.but my sqlite database have been createad on  the server,but i wanted it to be on the visitor's device. I tought that sqlite was used for offline purpose for websites, i'm a little bit confused plz help me

---

My script:

```
class MyDB extends SQLite3 { 
    function __construct() {
        $this->open('mysqlitedb.db');
    }
}

$db = new MyDB();
```

It is created on my server not on the device

Comment: What are you building? Are you building a website with PHP and SQLite that can be accessed from a phone/tablet/laptop/desktop/etc.?

Comment: Yes i'm building a website with php with a sqlite database for local use and mysql database for online use.and the website will be accessed from a phone

Comment: What does local use mean? Mobile phones and tables typically do not run web applications locally.

Comment: is it going to be a website or an application. are you going to open it using a browser installed on your mobile?

Comment: Local means mobile phone like android. I want to create a native web app by using the gonative.com website so it will be runned in browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have your database either on client device or server side or even in both locations. It really depends on your requirement. If each of your devices want hold their own data itself on the device, its enough to have a DB in client device. If you want to have any centralized location to hold all of your data, you can go for a DB located on your server.

Sq-lite is a lightweight DBMS and mostly used as a client side DBMS and not recommended to use as a server side implementation.

---

And also, Firefox doesn't support SQLite database (in web pages). And it's not part of the HTML5 specification anymore. IndexedDB is the standardized database: http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/ Mozilla,Chrome and others are working on it.

---

The codingg you have with you is in PHP, which is a serverside language and it will execute and perform all of its tasks on the server including DB creation.

---

I recomend you to use IndexedDB over SQ-Lite and to use javascript to handle it.

ex

```
var todoDB = (function() {
  var tDB = {};
  var datastore = null;

  // TODO: Add methods for interacting with the database here.

  // Export the tDB object.
  return tDB;
}());

/**
 * Open a connection to the datastore.
 */
tDB.open = function(callback) {
  // Database version.
  var version = 1;

  // Open a connection to the datastore.
  var request = indexedDB.open('todos', version);

  // Handle datastore upgrades.
  request.onupgradeneeded = function(e) {
    var db = e.target.result;

    e.target.transaction.onerror = tDB.onerror;

    // Delete the old datastore.
    if (db.objectStoreNames.contains('todo')) {
      db.deleteObjectStore('todo');
    }

    // Create a new datastore.
    var store = db.createObjectStore('todo', {
      keyPath: 'timestamp'
    });
  };

  // Handle successful datastore access.
  request.onsuccess = function(e) {
    // Get a reference to the DB.
    datastore = e.target.result;

    // Execute the callback.
    callback();
  };

  // Handle errors when opening the datastore.
  request.onerror = tDB.onerror;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply kuma dk. I want to use the client side sqlite for my website but i cant get to make it work.all the codes that i have seen only shows how to create the database,when i create it localy it is created in the same location as the script. So i want it to be on the device not on the server. How to do it?

Comment: What is the script that you are using currently. You should past it here along with the question.

Comment: Here is the script. class MyDB extends SQLite3
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->open('mysqlitedb.db');
    }
}

$db = new MyDB();
 But it is created on my server not on the device

Comment: Thx for your replies, but i tought that indexed db just jave 5mb of stockage space

Comment: You cant use even SQ-Lite since it is deprecated and not supported by major browsers.

Answer (score -1):

SQlite is not a real RDBMS but a single file. Thus, you cannot connect remotely as with MySQL and PostgreSQL databases. Also, SQlite is not database in a sense that supports transactions and data types. If you need database server to connect and keep data at one place, then you should replace SQlite.